# How do i create a logical value in R that is TRUE if the numbers are part of a specific category?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, logical-operators

I have to create a logical value named
is. a flush which is TRUE if and only if the hand is a flush - A flush is a hand that contains five cards all of the same suit. This is my dataset

```
deck <- data.frame(suit = rep(c("D","C","H","S"), 13),rank = rep(2:14, 4))
```

For reference= # D = ♦ Diamond, C = ♣ Club, H = ♥ Heart, S = ♠ Spade

11 = Jack, 12 = Queen, 13 = King, 14 = Ace

This is what I tried so far: I just picked manually 5 values that share the same suit and used the unique function to prove what i know already, however, this is clearly not a good way and I also am not creating any logical value.

```
hand <- deck[c(43,15,35,7,27),]
unique(hand)
```

Any help is appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You canch chek if all suits in `hand$suit` are equal to the first suit (`hand$suit[1]`) in that vector.

```
is.Flush <- all(hand$suit == hand$suit[1])
is.Flush

#> TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i get this error message: Error in hand$suit : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Perhaps you changed `hand` while you were working.  Try restarting your R session and run your code and then Johan's code.